# Using $.get("url",data) again in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to use the $.get() function to get data from a page, and then parse the data through jQuery, such as getting all the images, and then putting it into the body of the user's page.

```
$.get("/character/hats").done(function(data) {
   //$("body").prepend(data);
   /*data?*/$(".card > .card-body .col-md-4").each(function(){
     let hatdata=$(data).find('pull-left').html;
     let hatid=0;
     $("body").prepend('<p>found!</p><div>'+hatdata+'</div>');
     let assetcode=0;
     console.log("I see hat id" + "");
   });*/
});
```

Is there a way to use jQuery data response from $.get, and parse it using jQuery again?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm attempting to use the content from $.get, and then to use jQuery to get all the content in that $.get request, by going through all the items in the $.get request, using jQuery.

Comment: That's not a question... are you encountering an error? How is it not working

Comment: first look `.find('pull-left')` should be `.find('.pull-left')` if class and `.find('#pull-left')` if id

Comment: @Dolvik You're already doing what you want to do... the result of the $.get request is stored in the `data` variable. You just use that variable however you want.

Comment: But it doesn't find anything in .each, because it's using the current viewable user page, instead of the 'data' I'm getting from $.get.

Comment: You need to search inside the data variable for whatever item matches what you're looking for. It's impossible to tell what you want without seeing the response of /hats

Comment: So do I use $(data).find? I'm confused on how to parse the $.get data I need. It keeps parsing the data that's already on the user's page before the $.get request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the data sent back from `$.get` you merely need to reference it. You shouldn't convert it back to a jQuery object with `$()`.

Here's an example which gets a JSON response.

```
$.get('https://httpbin.org/get').done(function(data) { 
  console.log(data); // data is a variable which contains a parsed JSON response to a javascript object.
  console.log(data.url);
});
```

You can view what the response looks like here: https://httpbin.org/get

If the response of your server isnt JSON you will need to do something else.

If the response is HTML you can do it like this:

```
$.get('https://httpbin.org').done(function(data) { 
  console.log(data); // data is now a string of html, which you can insert other places
  $('.some-div').html(data);
});
```

`$(...)` can be used when you want to 'query' the page's DOM with jQuery. You can query a DOM element with regular Javascript, but it won't include lots of helpful methods like `.find()` or `.html()`. So basically you convert an element into a jquery element, which is like javascript on steroids, and adds more methods.

The response from `$.get` however will either be an object (if its JSON) or a string of html (if HTML). You can convert the string of HTML to jQuery, and parse that as well if that's what you want.

`$(data).find('.some-element-in-response')`

Comment: Is it possible to avoid setting a whole page to a hidden div? I don't necessarily want to show everything on the page. I'm wanting to use `$(".card > .card-body .col-md-4").each(function(){` to go through each item on that page, and then show information in the users viewable page.

Comment: This does technically work for me, as then I can simply `$(".hiddenpage .card > .card-body .col-md-4")`, but I don't want the browser to be attempting to download all the images that's from the $.get(data)

Comment: *"$(...) is only used when you want to 'query' the page's DOM "* is not true...wrapping html outside of the dom in `$()` works also

Comment: Hmm ok, I tweaked it

Answer (score 1):

`html()` is  function not a property name

Change:

```
let hatdata=$(data).find('pull-left').html;
```

To:

```
let hatdata=$(data).find('pull-left').html();
```

Comment: But `$(".card > .card-body .col-md-4").each(function(){` never ran because that is in 'data', so this error never occured for me to find yet.

Comment: Yes, and I'm wanting to use jQuery on that .get/.ajax data.

Comment: Should be `$(data).find(".card > .card-body .col-md-4").each..`. You can do virtually any parsing of `data` the same as if the elements are in the page.

Comment: Oh. I've probably been overthinking this if I was able to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can I did it but in different way. You need change some way and change few ajax setting like following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/character/hats",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        $(".card > .card-body .col-md-4").each(function(){
        let hatdata=$(data).find('pull-left').html;
        let hatid=0;
        $("body").prepend('<p>found!</p><div>'+hatdata+'</div>');
        let assetcode=0;
        console.log("I see hat id" + "");
    }
});
```

Comment: I was already able to get the content through .get, and prefer to use .get, over .ajax, to support browser data that authenticates the user viewing the page to get /character/hats.